# strip till delimeter in ant

Tags: ant

I have a target which will run a executable and get a version. But I need to remove stuff till the delimeter. Help me please.

```
<target name="tomcatVersion">
  <exec executable="${WT_HOME}/tomcat/bin/catalina.bat" outputproperty="tomcat.version">
    <arg value="version" />
    <redirector>
      <outputfilterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <containsstring contains="Server number:"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </outputfilterchain>
    </redirector>
  </exec>
  <echo message="${tomcat.version}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Update: single step loadresource method with thanks to Matt]*

You could do this by reading the output of the executable into a property and then filtering the property through a replaceregexp token filter to extract the string you require. For example:

```
<project default="get-version">

  <target name="get-version">
    <exec executable="bash" outputproperty="version.output">
      <arg value="ant"/>
      <arg value="-version"/>
    </exec>
    <loadresource property="version">
      <string value="${version.output}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="[^\d]*(\d.\d.\d).*" replace="\1"/>
        </tokenfilter>
        <striplinebreaks/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo level="info" message="version is: '${version}'"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Sample output:

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

get-version:
     [echo] version is: '1.8.2'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

(I am using `ant -version` as a handy stand in for whatever executable you are running. I am aware that Ant version can be got from Ant properties.)

With older versions of Ant (<1.7) you could do this in two steps:

1. Write the output of the executable to file
2. Read the file through a replaceregexp token filter

For example:

```
<project default="get-version">
  <target name="get-version">
    <exec executable="bash" output="version.out">
      <arg value="ant"/>
      <arg value="-version"/>
    </exec>
    <loadfile property="version" srcfile="version.out">
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="[^\d]*(\d.\d.\d).*" replace="\1"/>
        </tokenfilter>
        <striplinebreaks/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <echo level="info" message="version is: '${version}'"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Sample output

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.6.5 compiled on June 2 2005

$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

get-version:
     [echo] version is: '1.6.5'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Comment: I would execute the program directly, not all systems have bash.

Comment: The example with ant -version is a bad one, as for the ant version, there's a builtin Property named ${ant.version}. Also writing the output to a file and loadproperties afterwards is a wasteful overhead, as exec has attributes to catch the output from an executable : outputproperty for stdout, errorproperty for stderr and resultproperty for returncode. If you need some function to cut out a specific part use http://code.google.com/p/flaka/

Comment: You don't need to write to a file, at least if you're using a recent version of Ant, you can use a property, then use `loadresource` and a `string` resource. A similar question came up today, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287655/ant-equivalent-of-cut-sort-uniq/6291881#6291881

Comment: @matt Thanks. I saw that answer yesterday but didn't think to apply to this. There's some cool stuff in recent Ant versions. My development shop is stuck in the dark ages with older versions... Anyway, I've updated my answer to use the single-step loadresource method.

Answer (score 0):

The exec task has 3 attributes to catch the output from an executable :

- outputproperty => catches stdout
- errorproperty  => catches stderr
- resultproperty => catches returncode

[see Ant Manual for exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

So for your purpose :

1. use outputproperty to catch the
   version written to stdout
2. grep the versionstring from
   outputproperty via String replace
   function from [Ant Plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)

   ```
   <project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
     <exec executable="bash" outputproperty="bashversion">
       <arg value="--version"/>
     </exec>
     <fl:let>bashversion ::= '#{replace('${bashversion}','$2','(?s)(.+)(\d\.\d\.\d\(.\)?)(.+)')}'</fl:let>
     <fl:echo>
       Bashversion => ${bashversion}
     </fl:echo>
   </project>
   ```

output :

```
[fl:echo] Bashversion => 4.1.7(1)
```