# Ant equivalent of cut | sort | uniq

Tags: ant

In an Ant task I set a property which is a list of files. e.g.

```
web/src/main/test/com/whatever/Ralph
business/src/main/test/com/whatever/Alice
web/src/main/test/com/whatever/Bob
```

I would like to extract the set of subdirectories from this list. In bash I'd:

```
$ cat filename | cut -d'/' -f1 | sort | uniq
business
web
```

Is there a way I can do something similar in an Ant macro? It needs to run on Windows too, so `<exec>` is not an option.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a tip - you can replace `sort|uniq` with `sort -u`

Comment: Ah thanks for that. The magic of bash is never-ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [`loadresource` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) with a [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).  Something like this perhaps:

```
<property name="list.of.files">
web/src/main/test/com/whatever/Ralph
business/src/main/test/com/whatever/Alice
web/src/main/test/com/whatever/Bob
</property>

<loadresource property="dirs">
    <string value="${list.of.files}" />
    <filterchain>
        <replaceregex pattern="/.*" replace="" />
        <sortfilter />
        <uniqfilter />
    </filterchain>
</loadresource>

<echo message="${dirs}" />
```

Result:

```
 [echo] business
 [echo] web

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

In older versions of Ant (<1.7) you could do the same by writing the property out to a file, then using a `loadfile` task with filterchain.

Comment: What about [`loadresource`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) with a [`string`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#string) resource (and the same `filterchain`)?

Comment: @matt: much simpler, thanks.  I always forget about the power of Ant resources.